# require('yeoman-generator').generators.Base is deprecated

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've just installed yeoman in an empty directory and it prints out an error. This is what I did:

```
npm i yo -g

npm i generator-webapp -g
```

After that I throws an error:

```
require('yeoman-generator').generators.Base is deprecated. Use require('yeoman-generator').Base directly
```

then it hangs up my terminal. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug with `generator-webapp`, you should open an issue on their repository https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues

FWIW, `generator-webapp` is not really maintained anymore as the community mostly all move to `generator-gulp-webapp`. You can see the discussion the team was having over here https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/567